# How to remove space around an android TimePicker

Tags: java, android, padding, timepicker

I am unable to remove the space around the TimePicker:
I am scaling the TimePicker down to 40% but there is a lot of space around the TimePicker, which I am not able to remove.

I am using translationX and translationY to position the TimePicker.

Please find below the xml (layout) code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX="0.4"
        android:scaleY="0.4"
        android:translationX="-60dp"
        android:translationY="-20dp"
        android:background="#FFDDAA00" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Below the time spinner" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please find below the screenshot in the simulator:
http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1T9y7rt22pzeDwounqG6i5z9YgRMYA

As you can see the gap between the TimePicker and the Text below it is the space that I am unable to remove.
I set the backgroud of the TimePicker to highlight the actual TimePicker and the space around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like -

```
android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
```

and

```
android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
```

Reduce the value as per your requirement.

---

EDIT :

Try removing padding and margin from your activity.

Comment: Doesn't work, it seems to ignore the negative sign so the picker grows.